# Помогите реализовать поиск по Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть **DataGrid** и **TextBox**, вводишь значение в **TextBox** и в **Datagrid** отображается только нужная строка.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="сustomerDataGrid" Grid.Row = "2" Grid.Column = "2"   Grid.ColumnSpan = "3" HorizontalAlignment = "Stretch" VerticalAlignment = "Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" MouseDoubleClick="сustomerDataGrid_MouseDoubleClick" LayoutUpdated="сustomerDataGrid_LayoutUpdated">
        <DataGrid.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip Background="#90004455">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Margin="3" Foreground="White">Редактирование: 2 шелчка по содержимому ячейки.</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="3" Foreground="White">Удаление строки: выделить строку, нажать 'Delete'.</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="3" Foreground="White">Сортировка: по нажатию заглавия столбца.</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </ToolTip>
        </DataGrid.ToolTip>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="idCustomerColumn" Binding="{Binding IdCustomer}" Header="Id Заказчика" Width="Auto"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="nameColumn" Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Название организации" Width="Auto" CanUserSort="False"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="locationColumn" Header="Местоположение" Width="Auto" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text = "{Binding Location}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <ComboBox SelectedItem = "{Binding Location}" ItemsSource = "{StaticResource Location}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn >
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="addressColumn" Binding="{Binding Address}" Header="Адрес" Width="Auto" CanUserSort="False"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="phoneColumn" Binding="{Binding Phone}" Header="Телефон" Width="Auto" CanUserSort="False"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="emailColumn" Binding="{Binding Email}" Header="Почта/E-mail" Width="Auto" CanUserSort="False"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="representativeColumn" Binding="{Binding Representative}" Header="Представитель" Width="*" CanUserSort="False"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Само подключение к базе:

```
ProjectAdministratorDataSet projectAdministratorDataSet = ((ProjectAdministratorDataSet)(this.FindResource("projectAdministratorDataSet")));
        ProjectAdministratorDataSetTableAdapters.СustomerTableAdapter projectAdministratorDataSetСustomerTableAdapter = new ProjectAdministratorDataSetTableAdapters.СustomerTableAdapter();
        projectAdministratorDataSetСustomerTableAdapter.Fill(projectAdministratorDataSet.Сustomer);
        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource сustomerViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("сustomerViewSource")));
        сustomerViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
```

А вот мой вариант поиска, но ничего не работает:

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
string login = textBox.Text;
        string Connection = @"Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=ProjectAdministrator; Integrated Security=True";
        string SelectQuery = "SELECT [IdCustomer] FROM [ProjectAdministrator].[dbo].[Customer] WHERE [IdCustomer] = '" + login + "'";
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SelectQuery, Connection);
        DataSet a = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(a);
        сustomerDataGrid.ItemsSource = a.Tables[0].DefaultView;
}
```

Comment: Приведите код в порядок, пожалуйста, а то не понятно что написано....

Comment: Вот так должно быть лучше)

Answer (score 1):

Решение найдено!

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioButton.IsChecked == true)
        {
            string id = textBox.Text;
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=ProjectAdministrator; Integrated Security=True");
            cn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Сustomer WHERE IdCustomer = '" + id + "'", cn);
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter.Fill(table);
            if (table.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Такого значения несушествует");
                cn.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                DataSet a = new DataSet();
                dataAdapter.Fill(a);
                сustomerDataGrid.ItemsSource = a.Tables[0].DefaultView;
                cn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: О боги. Построение запроса SQL конкатенацией. `== true`. Нет `using()`.

Comment: Увы, но мои знания в wpf и C# не очень продвинутые, уровень новичок, делал как мог. А с **using()** я так и не понял, где я находил - его не ставят при таком способе подключения, на 10 человек у  1 было