# Как можно реализовать поиск по Datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Полностью аналогичный вопрос тому, что задавался раньше на этом форуме - [Помогите реализовать поиск по Datagrid](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/537387/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be-datagrid)
Вопрос, как можно иначе это организовать? не используя MVVM. Можно это сделать без указания строки подключения к БД? У меня база подключена через ADO и я не использую его. Как правильно реализовать это можно?
грид вывожу этой строкой

```
            DGComplectViev.ItemsSource = NormApparatYchetEntities2.GetContext().ComplectTable.ToList();
```

Comment: `ToList()` - источником данных у вас является `List<T>`. Вот по нему и ищите. Хоть циклом, хоть линком.

Comment: можно ссылку на то как искать этими способами?

Comment: сделал так  var filter_col = sourceCollection.Where(itemF => itemF.NameComplect == TextPoick.Text);
            DGComplectViev.ItemsSource = filter_col;

Comment: но если удалить буквы, то он не будет показывать полный список

Comment: окей починил) но другая проблема, как сделать поск по типу значение*

Answer (score 0):

Вам можно использовать посредника в источнике данных в виде BindingSource. Источник для DG будет BindingSource, а для BindingSource уже ваш List. В BindigSource есть свойство Filter, с помощью него можно удобно поиск сделать, вот почитайте.
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_BindingSource_Filter

Comment: Идея хорошая, но, к сожалению, если к BindingSource привязать List, то свойство `SupportsFiltering` будет выдавать `false`. Такая связка не поддерживает фильтрацию.

Comment: и как быть тогда